# How to enable a user to access vpn in active directory

Tags: c#

how to enable a user to access vpn in active directory using c# programming language.

```
     string username = "Abc user";  
     string _path;
     string _filterAttribute;

    try
       {
      DirectoryEntry myLdapconnection=new DirectoryEntry("domain");  
      myLdapconnection.Path  = "LDAP://OU=,OU=,DC=,DC=,DC=";  
      myLdapconnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure; 

        object obj = myLdapconnection.NativeObject;
      DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapconnection);  
      search.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";
     search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                   s="True";
        if (null == result)
        {
            s= "false";
        }

        // Update the new path to the user in the directory.
        _path = result.Path;

        _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        s="Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message;
    }
```

from the above code what the function of following statement is?

```
  object obj = myLdapconnection.NativeObject;
```

Is this the statement to enable vpn?

if I add user to group then will he can use vpn connection?

Answer (score 0):

Since `obj` is not used in the above code; it has no function and has nothing to do with VPN.

The code seems like it is trying to verify that a user exists, BUT it is weird.

Comment: if I add user to group then will he can use vpn connection?